# When does dispose() get called on a ChangeNotifier?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-change-notifier

My question stems from the Flutter Documentation on simple state management,

> ... Note that we’re defining a builder that creates a new instance of CartModel. ChangeNotifierProvider is smart enough not to rebuild CartModel unless absolutely necessary. It also automatically calls dispose() on CartModel when the instance is no longer needed.

When does `dispose()` get called on some given ChangeNotifier model?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should call **any** `dispose` methods of any created instances which provide it in `dispose` method of the `State` class of `StatefulWidget`.

```dart
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  ...
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  final valueNotifier = VakueNotifier<int>(0);

  @override
  void dispose() {
    valueNotifier.dispose();  // dispose resources etc
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```